# Export FusionCharts chart as base64 data url string for use in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, fusioncharts

I would like to export FusionChart to a base64 data url string so that I can import it into a jsPDF pdf using jsPDF 'addImage'.

I have an example with a chart but using a fake base64 image here (click 'create pdf'):
http://jsfiddle.net/v3uLg6v6/

The relevant code is:

```
create_pdf = function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
    doc.addImage(fake_export, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
    doc.save('jsfiddle_export.pdf');
}
```

I would like to replace 'fake_export' with the base64 png version of the fusion chart (visitChart).

I was hoping for a getPNGString method similar to getSVGString, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FusionCharts API method `getSVGString` to get SVG string for rendered chart which can be converted to base64 string.

Check [this example for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/sikrigagan/2ovov3nL/).

Comment: jsPDF doesn't support SVG... I need the export to png to be provided as a data url instead of a downloadable file.

Comment: @FishBulbX SVG string generated using `getSVGString` can be converted to base64 using `window.btoa()` with PNG encoding.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible? Can you demonstrate in your example? The results are currently the base64 encoding of the svg vector image, not a png data url.